# Cannot feed dataframe containing also array column in Sklearn MLPClassifier

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I'm rather new for Python and dataframes. I have dataframe where one column is array (mfcc data from wav, arrays in all rows have the same length 273), others are float columns.
Code is rather simple:

```
train_mfccs, test_mfccs, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(df, Y, test_size=0.1, shuffle= True)

clf = MLPClassifier(max_iter=150)
clf.fit(train_mfccs, train_labels)
```

I cannot put the whole dataframe in fit method because of error - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I successfully can get results if I leave in dataframe only array column, or only float columns, but not both.
Also I tried to play around with np array without results because it requires for each new column to be the same shape as the first one.
I tried simple way of adding column of the same shape and then fill the first value only.

But this gives unexpected shape (50000, 1638) though I wanted (50000,2) where:

- first column is initial arrays with length of 273
- second is new array with length of 273 and with first value equal to attr1.

```
X = np.array(list(df['mfcc']), dtype=np.float)
X0 = np.zeros((50000,273))
for index, value in enumerate(df['attr1']):
        X0[index][0] = value
X = np.hstack((X,X0))
```

Is this possible to achieve - one column is array, others are not?

Answer (score 0):

We can just add inner array data as main dataframe columns.

**Example**: we have data in array column like this:

[image]

To create list of columns we can generate columns names:

```
mfccColNames = list(map(str, range(maxlen)))
print(mfccColNames)
```

So we get numbers as column names:

> ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'... '272']

And then fill dataframe:

```
df_x = pd.DataFrame(df['mfcc'].to_list(), columns=mfccColNames)
```

This results in all inner array data added as columns to dataframe which can be used in sklearn now.
Then we can add other columns from previous dataframe as needed.

[image]